# Creating a model within a model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is it possible to create a model object from within another model form?

Let's say I have an `Article` model and a `Term` model who have a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship through a join table. (Terms are almost like tags, but have a definition column.)

I want the user to be able to add terms to the article when editing it (probably using check boxes), but I also the user to be able to create a new term if he can't find it in the list. How can this be done? I want the user to be able to create a term with a definition inside the article edit form. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Read into "nested objects" or "nested attributes". This might be a good starting point: http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes

Answer (score 0):

You could always separate the fields inside the params hash (hashes with different keys, likely :term => {} and :article => {}) that is passed back to the controller and then handle it separately once you are in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

Ryan on railscasts shows how to do something similar in these two screencasts. He adds questions and answers to a survey website.

[Nested Model Form 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)

[Nested Model Form 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2)

Along with that this resource on
[nested attributes](http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2009/2/1/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-nested-attributes) will help you piece it all together.