# RoR, How should I model this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, server-side

I asked this question earlier but I was very vague and a lot of people suggested that since I am just starting with Ruby and RoR, maybe it's better if I focus on "Hello, World!" first. I appreciate that the answers were honest, but this is part of my project so I have to get it done. And I want to get it done right so there's less problems later on.

What I am trying to do is this:

I am making a web application that basically allows user to create a
table. They name the table and add multiple columns (fields). Then they
add
entries (rows), just like a typical table.

So for example, the user can create a table called "High-Scores". Then
add fields "Name", "Points", "Achievements". These 3 will be the
columns. Then they can add an entry, so for example, "John", "123",
"Gold".

How would I model this with a Active-Records Base subclass? Basically, from what I have
learned from tutorial so far, the models have predetermined fields. Now,
I have dynamic fields.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have not tried it, but you should be able to [create tables](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-create_table) and [add columns](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_column) easily with ActiveRecord. As for models having predetermined fields - that's not really accurate. ActiveRecord determines the field names from the database table itself - they are "predetermined" in that sense. Also, you might(?) need to reload models / other .rb files when you change the schema.

Comment: This might help you      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095567/creating-a-model-within-a-model-in-rails

Comment: For such data model it would be better to use MongoDb instead of SQL

Comment: It would be good to know what you're actually planning on doing with this user created data. From the example you've given I'd suggest using a key-value store like Redis, but it's really hard to say without knowing how you are planning to use this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your requirements. You shouldnt really create new tables for each user if thats not the specific goal of your application. If you just want the user to enter data in a "table" on your webpage you can model a table in four tables one for the `TableName`, one for the `ColumnName`, one for each `TableEntry` and one for each column in a TableEntry called `EntryValue`.

It will be tricky to create the view for that but its possible.